# Writing a native messaging host in GJS

Tags: glib, chrome-native-messaging, gjs

I'm trying to write a [native messaging host](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-host-protocol) for a chrome/firefox extension in GJS (since it will rely on code already written in GJS) but encountering some hurdles. I'm using [chrome-gnome-shell](https://github.com/GNOME/chrome-gnome-shell/blob/master/connector/chrome-gnome-shell.py) as a rough template since it also uses GLib/Gio instrospection and GApplication, but it has the advantage of python `struct` that I don't have.

Quickly, native messaging hosts exchange messages through stdin/stdout which are an Int32 (4-bytes) length following by a string of utf-8 encoded JSON.

chrome-gnome-shell uses `GLib.IOChannel` with `set_encoding('utf-8')` and `struct` to handle int32 bytes. I've had trouble using that class in GJS and don't have `struct` so have been trying `Gio.UnixInputStream` wrapped in `Gio.DataInputStream` (and output counterparts), with `put_int32()`/`read_int32()` and `put_string()`/`read_string()`.

Apparently I'm mightily confused about what I'm doing. If I call `Gio.DataInputStream.read_int32()` it returns a number `369098752`, so I'm guessing the int32 is not being converted to a regular Number. If I call `Gio.DataInputStream.read_bytes(4, null).unref_to_array()` to get a ByteArray; `ByteArray.toString()` returns '\u0016' while ByteArray[0] returns '22' which appears to be the actual length.

Some pointers on reading/writing int32's to a datastream and would be much appreciated.

chrome-gnome-shell references:

- [on_input()](https://github.com/GNOME/chrome-gnome-shell/blob/master/connector/chrome-gnome-shell.py#L205)
- [send_message()](https://github.com/GNOME/chrome-gnome-shell/blob/master/connector/chrome-gnome-shell.py#L292)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to solve this, but here's what I came up with.

Two functions using the ByteArray import (modified from somewhere on SO):

```
const ByteArray = imports.byteArray;

function fromInt32 (byteArray) {
    var value = 0;

    for (var i = byteArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        value = (value * 256) + byteArray[i];
    }

    return value;
};

function toInt32 (num) {
    var byteArray = [0, 0, 0, 0];

    for (var index_ = 0; index_ < byteArray.length; index_++) {
        var byte = num & 0xff;
        byteArray [index_] = byte;
        num = (num - byte) / 256 ;
    }

    return ByteArray.fromArray(byteArray);
};
```

For receiving/sending:

```
const Gio = imports.gi.Gio;

// Receiving
let stdin = new Gio.DataInputStream({
    base_stream: new Gio.UnixInputStream({ fd: 0 })
});

let int32 = stdin.read_bytes(4, null).toArray();
let length = fromInt32(int32);
let data = stdin.read_bytes(length, null).toArray().toString();
let message = JSON.parse(data);

// Sending
let stdout = new Gio.DataOutputStream({
    base_stream: new Gio.UnixOutputStream({ fd: 1 })
});

let data = JSON.stringify(message);
let int32 = toInt32(data.length);
stdout.write(int32, null);
stdout.put_string(data, null);
```

Of course, you should wrap these in try-catch as appropriate and you'll probably want to connect a source to the input (you can use the Gio.UnixInputStream):

```
let source = stdin.base_stream.create_source(null);
source.set_callback(onReceiveFunc);
source.attach(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [`Gio.DataOutputStream.put_int32()`](http://devdocs.baznga.org/gio20~2.50p/gio.dataoutputstream#method-put_int32) and [`Gio.DataInputStream.read_int32()`](http://devdocs.baznga.org/gio20~2.50p/gio.datainputstream#method-read_int32) the same way as you use `read_bytes()` and `put_string()`.

Comment: I did try using `read_int32()` and `put_int32()`, but these don't seem to be converting to/from a standard base-10 javascript Number, but instead return a gigantic number. Is this possibly a GJS/GIR bug?

Comment: Yes, sounds like a bug. The bug tracker is now at gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs

Comment: Neat, code highlighting and stuff ;) Bug report here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/issues/20